# How to redirect to List View Page in PHP CodeIgniter using parameters after submitting a form?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to my list view page when I'm entering a data into form and submit that form.

In my case, I'm trying to enter room details for particular property by passing `property ID` and after submitting to the form it will redirect to the **property list**, but I want to redirect to the **room list**.

**Here is my code:**

*Controller:*

```
public function viewRoom($id)
{
    $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    $data['username'] = $user->username;
    $data['user_id'] = $user->id;
    $data['usertype'] = $user->type;

    $data['title'] = 'View Rooms';

    $data['property'] = $this->p->fetchProperty($id);
    $data['views'] = $this->p->view_Room($id);

    $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('Property/property_view_room', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}

public function addRoom($id)
{
    $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    $data['username'] = $user->username;
    $data['user_id'] = $user->id;
    $data['usertype'] = $user->type;

    $data['title'] = 'Add New Rooms';

    $data['roomtype'] =$this->p->selectRoomType();
    $data['yesnotype'] = $this->p->selectYesNoType();
    $data['bedroomtype'] = $this->p->selectBedroomType();

    $data['property'] = $this->p->fetchProperty($id);
    $data['views'] = $this->p->view_Room($id);

    $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('Property/property_add_room', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}

public function submitRoom()
{
    $result = $this->p->submitAddRoom();

    if ($result) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Rooms added successfully');
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg','Faill to add Rooms');
    }
    redirect(base_url('property'));
    //redirect(base_url('property/viewRoom'.$id));
}
```

*Model:*

```
public function view_Room($id)
{
    $query =$this->db->query('call fetch_View_Room(?)',$id);
    if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
        $data =$query->result();
        $query->next_result();
        $query->free_result();
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function submitAddRoom()
{
    $sql ="call insert_Room(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                                  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $this->db->query($sql, array(
        'user_id'=>$this->input->post('user_id'),
        'room_landlord_id'=>$this->input->post('room_landlord_id'),
        'room_property_id'=>$this->input->post('room_property_id'),
        'room_custom_number'=>$this->input->post('room_custom_number'),
        'room_name'=>$this->input->post('room_name'),
        'room_type'=>$this->input->post('room_type'),
        'room_location'=>$this->input->post('room_location'),
        'room_notes'=>$this->input->post('room_notes'),
        'room_size'=>$this->input->post('room_size'),
        'room_fire_escape'=>$this->input->post('room_fire_escape'),
        'room_fire_doors'=>$this->input->post('room_fire_doors'),
        'room_bedroom_type'=>$this->input->post('room_bedroom_type'),
        'room_wc'=>$this->input->post('room_wc'),
        'room_sink'=>$this->input->post('room_sink'),
        'room_shower'=>$this->input->post('room_shower'),
        'room_extractor_fan'=>$this->input->post('room_extractor_fan'),
        // 'room_images'=>$this->input->do_upload('room_images'),
        'room_double_door'=>$this->input->post('room_double_door')
    ));
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

*View:*

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('Property/submitRoom'); ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">

</form>
```

Am I made any mistake while passing parameter ? How to pass parameter in submit() function ?

**Update:**
[image]

Any kind of help is welcome, Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `redirect(base_url('property'));` to your room list route

Comment: It gives an error, I just comment out that line in code, because I want to show list of rooms that are associated with particular property (I'm passing property ID).

Comment: What happened when you used redirect(base_url('property/viewRoom'.$id)); ? And where is your viewRoom method in your property controller?

Comment: Please check updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller `addRoom` function like this

```
public function addRoom($id)
{
    $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    $data['username'] = $user->username;
    $data['user_id'] = $user->id;
    $data['usertype'] = $user->type;

    $data['title'] = 'Add New Rooms';

    $data['roomtype'] =$this->p->selectRoomType();
    $data['yesnotype'] = $this->p->selectYesNoType();
    $data['bedroomtype'] = $this->p->selectBedroomType();

    $data['property'] = $this->p->fetchProperty($id);
    $data['views'] = $this->p->view_Room($id);
    $data['property_id'] = $id;

    $this->load->view('template/header', $data); 
    $this->load->view('Property/property_add_room', $data); 
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

get property id from form request

```
public function submitRoom()
{   

    $result = $this->p->submitAddRoom();
    $id = $this->input->post('id'); //property id

    if ($result) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Rooms added successfully');
    }else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg','Faill to add Rooms');
    }
    //redirect(base_url('property'));
    redirect(base_url('property/viewRoom'.$id));
}
```

add hidden of property id filed to your form like

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('Property/submitRoom'); ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $property_id; ?>">
</form>
```